# How do i get the row Count from my Database after i've scaffolded it with EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

i'm trying to learn how to work with entityframeworkCore for an academic project and i'm stuck at manipulating my scaffolded database as it is (in c#) .

for example i'm making a simple REST api that will retrun the number of people in my database (Sql-Server).

```
  [HttpGet("(Id)")]
    public String GetAdminList(int Id)
    {

        return "get me "+Id+" admins !";
    }
```

- 

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RAZORING.Models.DBContextClass _context;

    public IndexModel(RAZORING.Models.DBContextClass context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<AdmUser> AdmUser { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        AdmUser = await _context.AdmUsers
            .Include(a => a.AdmUserAdmRoleFk1Navigation)
            .Include(a => a.AdmUserCfgTierFk1Navigation).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

this is the indexModel for the razor page that lists the table in question

the Scaffolded database is in an other project in the same solution and i have referenced it but i don't even know where to begin to be able to manipulate the tables, i have made a razor mvs webApp to confirm that it works but that's it.

Any help would be much appreciated even with a documentation as i haven't found much information online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of AdmUsers in the database would be given by:

```
_context.AdmUsers.Count();
```

EF will take this LINQ and translate it to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdmUsers`

You don't "manipulate tables" per se; you treat things as collections of entities, and leave EF to worry about "manipulating tables" (creating SQL that manipualtes data in tables). This "manipulates a table [entity]" for example:

```
var u = _context.admUsers.Find(1234); //retrieve user 1234
u.FirstName = "Hello"; //change name
_context.SaveChanges(); //write new name to db. note, if you're in a position to be using async, then `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` may be better
```

This works because when you download user 1234, EF keeps track of it. If you change its properties, EF will see the changes and can save them

Many things that you can do with LINQ will be translated to queries. Getting all the users in a city:

```
var usrs = _context.Users.Where(u => u.City == "Chicago").ToArray();

//probably becomes SELECT * FROM Users WHERE City = 'Chicago'
```

Move everyone to new york:

```
foreach(var u in usrs)
  u.City = "New York";
_context.SaveChanges();
```

---

Sometimes EF can't translate the expressions you use, so you'll get an error:

```
var twentyYrOlds = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Age.ToString("00").Substring(0, 1) == "2").ToArray();
```

Here it's quite likely (I'll never say never) that EF couldn't translate the ToString with formatting, and subsequent substring to the SQL equivalent. You need to write the query in a different way that it can translate:

```
var twentyYrOlds = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Age >= 20 && u.Age < 30).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks ! i'll be using this information to better understand EF